# asp.net Form Generator

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Anyone know of a product/solution that creates web forms on the fly?  I want to allow my users to create their own web forms.  Any help is appreciated.  C# or VB solutions accepted.

Edit: What I'm trying to create is something like [wufoo.com](http://wufoo.com) (thanks o.k.w).  I don't want to have to build my own form builder from scratch.

Comment: Are you refering to something like Wufoo? (http://wufoo.com/)

Comment: I would like to import a form builder into my project like I would for a 3rd party control..

Comment: What was your final solution for this?

Comment: I ended up creating a set of ascx controls that contained the control(s) that I wanted and then adding them to the page dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scaffolding in sub sonic 3.0 will let you do that.

http://subsonicproject.com/

Maybe you can extend it by letting users create the forms..

Did you look at dotnetnuke?